# Why Can't I Click "Enable" in Google Cloud to Enable Map GeoCoding?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-platform

I was referred here after positing this problem Google's forum:

https://support.google.com/maps/thread/10640635?hl=en

I am at the point now where I have a new API key, have billing enabled, and still can't enable GeoCoding due to grayed out box that will never render right no matter how many times I reload. Whenever I do a simple map using the Maps JavaScript API I get an error saying that I can't display it properly and can only use it for development purposes even though that API is enabled.

Comment: You can't click "enable" because it is broken.  Only Google can fix that.  Not sure why they directed you here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Yea, it really doesn't

Answer (score 0):

This mysterious problem has mysteriously fixed itself. I can now enable whatever without this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was due an issue with the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) : https://issuetracker.google.com/138349248

It has already been fixed as of Jul 26, 2019 12:11PM.

Comment: clicked on the b.corp.google.com link, thought it was a phishing attempt, then looked at the certs and looks legit. Why are you posting links behind a login wall?